# AJAX not receiving POST variables

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

I've read at least 20 of these similar questions and can't figure out what's wrong with my code.

I've got a login form as shown below:

```
<div class="login-form">
    <form class="login-form-container" action="./" method="post" autocomplete="off">
        <input id="login-user" type="text" placeholder="&#xf007; Username"/>
        <input id="login-pass" type="password" placeholder="&#xf023; Password"/>
    <div class="login-button-container">
        <input id="login-button" type="submit" value="Log in"/>
    </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

My login.js script is as below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#login-button").click(function(e){
    var username = $("#login-user").val();
    var password = $("#login-pass").val();
    $.ajax({url: "../includes/index.php", //.js file is in a diff directory
        data: {'login':true,'name':username,'pwd':password},
        type: "POST",
        success: function(html) {    
            if (html=='true') {
             //window.location="dashboard.php";
             alert('success');
            }
            else {
                alert('failure');
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
    });
});
```

This is supposed to get sent back to 'index.php', which has included a separate php file that handles the login information. The reason for this is so I can update the page with the user's successful login without refreshing.

My other php file is simply checking for the post data:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    var_dump($_POST);
    if (isset($_POST['login']) && $_POST['login']) {
    } else if (isset($_POST['reg']) && $_POST['reg']) { //this is for registration, which will be used once this login is working
    } else {
        echo 'Neither login/reg were set';
    }
```

The var dump shows:

```
array(0) { }
```

So the data is not being received. However, it clearly reaches the php page. I don't know what's wrong, any suggestions?

Edit: I figured I would add, that adding an alert at the top of login.js with the username/password does print the entered values. So the login.js is being reached, and the data is accessible there. But it doesn't go beyond that.

Edit2: Here is my updated HTML and login.js code:

index.php:

```
<form class="login-form-container" action="./" method="post" autocomplete="off">
    <input id="login-user" type="text" placeholder="&#xf007; Username"/>
        <input id="login-pass" type="password" placeholder="&#xf023; Password"/>
        <div class="login-button-container">
            <input id="login-button" type="button" value="Log in"/>
        </div>
</form>
```

login.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert(1);
$("#login-button").click(function(e){
    alert(0);
    //e.preventDefault();
    var username = $("#login-user").val();
    var password = $("#login-pass").val();
    $.ajax({url: "../includes/index.php",
        data: {'login':true,'name':username,'pwd':password},
        type: "POST",
        success: function(html) {    
            if (html=='true') {
             //window.location="dashboard.php";
             alert('success');
            }
            else {
                alert('failure');
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
});
});
```

Comment: How does it clearly reach the page if var dump is empty?

Comment: because it confirms that "$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'", simply loading the index page does not dump anything..unless I'm mistaken about this?

Comment: Any error in console?

Comment: Your ajax does not display the response, so where are you seeing `array(0) { }` displayed?

Comment: @Steve I am seeing it on index.php after I submit any values to the login form. It also echoes that login/reg were not set.

Comment: @Gredenko if you var_dump($_POST) and there's no post at all it still will give you array() as an output, for future reference

Comment: So you mean you navigate to index php? Thats a completely separate request

Comment: @Gredenko can you add a screenshot of the request from the network tab?

Comment: @Steve when sending the data through the login (which is on index.php), the ajax loads index.php with the post data (or no data in this case), so no I am not manually navigating to any page.

Comment: Also `../` is not a url, its a filepath. Maybe jquery has some built in handling of that, but i doubt it

Comment: if you are using ajax then how index.php will load?

Comment: Your ajax doesnt load anything, it just shows an alert?

Comment: ../ is just a relative path, which will be resolved by the browser.  It's not really a jquery concern.

Comment: @Shekhar Chikara I'm not sure if this is the screenshot you wanted but it does say GET. http://prntscr.com/f5v9h0

Comment: That screenshot shows the request for a css file, not the url you are trying to hit in the ajax call.  Find the XHR request for the url in the ajax request and examine it's parms in the header tab.  You should be able to see what data it is sending across and how.

Comment: @Taplar can you explain to me how to view the request? I haven't seen this before, sorry!

Comment: In that same screenshot, look up towards the top for an XHR tab.  Next to the highlighted "All" tab.

Comment: Your ajax is triggered by the forms submit button click event, but you dont stop the default behaviour (submitting the form), so the browser does a regular form post (the ajax probably never fires). As your form inputs dont have name attributes, they are not posted, hence the empty `$_POST` array

Comment: @Gredenko So in your Network tab, you should see a request going to `index.php`. Click on that and it will open up a sidebar with the request details. Please post a screenshot of that..

Comment: @Taplar the XHR tab shows nothing before and after sending a login.

Comment: instead of button type="submit" change it to type="button". clear console. before clicking it. then click button and trace the network tab of developer console.

Comment: @Steve I had preventDefault before, but that didn't affect it when I added it again just now.

Comment: set type attribute on the button to `type=button`, or attach to the forms submit event instead of a button click.

Comment: Do you even need ajax?

Comment: @AshokkumarM.Prajapati changing to 'button' makes the entire script stop working, and nothing appears on the XHR tab still.

Comment: Perfect. that indicates that your click event (js code) is not executing. Keep the type button. and now use alert in you click event to see if it fires.

Comment: @AshokkumarM.Prajapati No it does not, am I supposed to keep the same login.js script while changing to "button"?

Comment: yes. just put one alert inside document ready function and another in click event to see if they are getting fired. Also, you login.js files get cached in browser. so please where you are including the js try a query string at end to remove cache. so, login.js?version=1.2 should be included.

Comment: @Steve is there another way to update a section of my page with successful login, without refreshing? I wanted my "Login" area to update this way.

Comment: @AshokkumarM.Prajapati I have updated my include and added another alert. It alerts on document ready but not on click.

Comment: No, if no page refresh is a requirement, you will need ajax. Its just that you hadn't seemed to notice your code wasnt using ajax, so i thought you might be able to do without it.

Comment: Please update you latest html & jquery code.

Comment: @AshokkumarM.Prajapati Done, please see my edit2.

Comment: @AshokkumarM.Prajapati I have gotten my js script to start working a little more, changing it to "$(document).on("click","#login-button",function(e) {", which does send the request. Thank you, my errors are now SQL related which I can handle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to change my

```
$("#login-button").click(function(e){
```

to

```
$(document).on("submit",".login-form-container",function(e) {
```

which will handle the form submit, and this includes pressing the button as well as hitting enter (ideal situation).

Now the data is being sent successfully and I can handle the actual login/registration SQL, so thank you to @Ashokkumar M. Prajapati for helping to come to the conclusion that the .js script was not actually firing upon submit (not that the rest of you didn't help!)

Answer (score -1):

please replace `type: "POST"` with `method: "POST"`
you mentioned it wrong in jquery ajax function.

Default is "GET" in case you don't specify it. So, if you had checked both $_POST & $_GET then you would have found your data in $_GET.

try var_dump($_REQUEST) if it don't show up anything then your client is not sending data to server.

also, check net panel of you browser developer console. so, you will know what data are passed to server.

Comment: From the docs. "An alias for method. You should use type if you're using versions of jQuery prior to 1.9.0."

Comment: `type` is an alias for `method`. Using `method` won't change anything in this case..

Comment: The issue is that the browser performs a regular form post, the ajax probably never fires.